# Jquery Autocomplete with Ajax Call not working

Tags: ajax, materialize, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Im adding enhancements to an existing rails 5.1 app.  I need to add autocomplete with data retrieved from a Mysql database.  The application has Jquery, simple_form, and materialize all included.  My autocomplete is not working.  It is not even getting to the controller.  I have tried different examples found online and none work.  I am hoping someone can help me.

HTML in HAML code snippet (only snippet)

```
= simple_form_for @vehicle, url: url_for(controller: 'trip_permits', action: 'update'), html: { method: :patch } do |v|

       .input-field.col.s12.m4
        =v.label :registration_number
        = v.text_field :registration_number, input_html: { class: 'force-upcase' }
     .cssbuttons.alternate
      -# = link_to 'Cancel', '#', onclick: "$('.new_vehicle').hide();", class: 'btn btn-grey'
      %button{ type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-green', id: 'add'}
        Add
Id of field is generated to trip_permits_vehicles_form_registration_number

JQUERY SNIPPET


`
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
``
            $("#trip_permit_vehicle_form_registration_number").autocomplete(
              {
                  search: function () {},
                  source: function (request, response)
                  {
                      $.ajax(
                        {
                                                url:'/customers/trip_permits/autocomplete_vehicle_registration_number',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data:
                              {
                                  term: request.term,
                              },
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                  },
                  minLength: 2,
                  select: function (event, ui)
                  {
                      var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
                      if (test > 0)
                      {
                          alert(test);
                      }
                  }
              });
        }
});

I know I am missing something.  Im not worried right now about the results because I cant even get the ajax call to work.

Can someone please help????
```

I have tried all the examples I could find online
Ive tried select2, simple_form_autocomplete, materialize-autocomplete

Comment: what is `search: function () {},` doing? I'm not seeing anything about that in any jqueryUI autocomplete documentation

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("#trip_permit_vehicle_form_registration_number").autocomplete({
  search: function () {},
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON( 
      "/customers/trip_permits/autocomplete_vehicle_registration_number", 
      {term: request.term },
      response
    );
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function (event, ui){
    var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
    if (test > 0) { alert(test); }
  }
})
```

Comment: No, This code isnt working, i set a breakpoint in devtool and its not even stopping.
In the code i sent it stops at the autocomlete function but doesnt even seem to be entering it.